# add an image to a create a puzzle in a 16 by 16 grid html & javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried doing the necessary but cannot get a single image to appear broken up into 16 pieces.  here is my code to the original with no image and works with the numbers 1-15

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPEhtmlPUBLIC"-//W3C//DTDXHTML1.0Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!--Exercise12.8:Solution-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Solution12.8</title>
<style type="text/css">
    span{font-size:4em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    color:blue}
    table{border-collapse:collapse}
    td{border:2px solid gray;
    width:5em}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var cells;
    var swapped;

    function setup()
    {
    // create a 2d array of all the cells
        cells = new Array(
          [ document.getElementById("cell00"),
            document.getElementById("cell01"),
            document.getElementById("cell02"),
            document.getElementById("cell03") ],
          [ document.getElementById("cell10"),
            document.getElementById("cell11"),
            document.getElementById("cell12"),
            document.getElementById("cell13") ],
          [ document.getElementById("cell20"),
            document.getElementById("cell21"),
            document.getElementById("cell22"),
            document.getElementById("cell23") ],
          [ document.getElementById("cell30"),
            document.getElementById("cell31"),
            document.getElementById("cell32"),
            document.getElementById("cell33") ] );

        placeNumbers();
    }

        function placeNumbers()
        {
        var numbers = new Array();
        var randomLoc;
        var temp;

        for(var i=0; i < 16;i++)
        numbers[i]= i;

        for(i = 0; i <16;i++)
        {
        randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random()*15+1);
        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[randomLoc];
        numbers[randomLoc] = temp;
        }

        i=0;
        for (var rows=0;rows<4;rows++)
            for(var cols = 0;cols<4;cols++)
            {
                if ( numbers[i] != 0) 
                cells[rows][cols].innerHTML = numbers[i];
                else
                cells[rows][cols].innerHTML="";

                ++i;
                }
                }

                function doClick(row,col)
                {
                var top = row-1;
                var bottom = row + 1;
                var left = col - 1;
                var right = col + 1;

                swapped = false;

                if (top != -1 && cells[top][col].innerHTML=="")
                swap(cells[row][col], cells[top][col]);
                else if ( right != 4 &&
                cells[row][right].innerHTML =="")
                swap(cells[row][col],cells[row][right]);
                else if (bottom != 4 &&
                cells[bottom][col].innerHTML == "")
                swap (cells[row][col],cells[bottom][col]);
                else if ( left != -1 && 
                cells[row][left].innerHTML=="")
                swap(cells[row][col],cells[row][left]);
                else
                alert("An Illegal move has been made.  Please click on a number nearest the blank space");

                checkWin();
                }

                function swap(firstCell,secondCell)
                {
                swapped = true;
                secondCell.innerHTML=firstCell.innerHTML;
                firstCell.innerHTML="";
                }

                function checkWin()
                {
                    var win = true;

                    for (var i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)
                        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                            if (!(cells[i][j].innerHTML == i*4 + j + 1))
                                if (!(i == 3 && j == 3))
                                    win = false;
                        if (win)
                            if ( window.prompt( "Would you like to play again?", "yes") )
                                placeNumbers();
                            else
                            alert ("Game Over. Thank you for playing");
                 }
                //-->
                </script>
                </head>
                <body onload="setup()">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(0,0)"id="cell00"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(0,1)"id="cell01"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(0,2)"id="cell02"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(0,3)"id="cell03"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(1,0)"id="cell10"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(1,1)"id="cell11"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(1,2)"id="cell12"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(1,3)"id="cell13"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(2,0)"id="cell20"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(2,1)"id="cell21"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(2,2)"id="cell22"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(2,3)"id="cell23"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(3,0)"id="cell30"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(3,1)"id="cell31"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(3,2)"id="cell32"/></td>
                    <td> <span onclick = "doClick(3,3)"id="cell33"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying for the image here is the code but i cannot get it to work...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>12.9</title>

<style type = "text/css">
    table{border-collapse:collapse}
    td{border:1px solid gray;}

</style>
<script type= "text/javascript">
    <--
    var cells;
    var swapped;

    function setup()
    {
        //create a 2d array of cells
        cells = new Array (
        [ document.getElementById("cell00"),
          document.getElementById("cell01"),
          document.getElementById("cell02"),
          document.getElementById("cell03")],
        [ document.getElementById("cell10"),
          document.getElementById("cell11"),
          document.getElementById("cell12"),
          document.getElementById("cell13")],
        [ document.getElementById("cell20"),
          document.getElementById("cell21"),
          document.getElementById("cell22"),
          document.getElementById("cell23")],
        [ document.getElementById("cell30"),
          document.getElementById("cell31"),
          document.getElementById("cell32"),
          document.getElementById("cell33") ] );

        placeNumbers();
    }

    function placeNumbers()
    {
        var numbers = new Array();
        var randomLoc;
        var temp;

        for (i= 0; i < 16; i++)
        numbers[i] = i + "9.gif";

        for (i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            randomLoc = Math.floor( Math.random() * 15 + 1 );
            temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[randomLoc];
            numbers[randomLoc] = temp;
        }

        i = 0;
        for (var rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
            for ( vars cols = 0; cols < 4; cols++;)
            {
            if (numbers [i] != "9.gif")
                {
                cells[rows][cols].src = numbers[i];
                cells[rows][cols].alt = numbers[i];
                }
            else
                {
                cells[rows][cols].style.display = "none";
                cells[rows][cols].alt = "hidden";
                cells[rows][cols].src = "9.gif";
                }

                ++i;
            }
    }

    function doClick( row, col)
    {
        var top = row - 1;
        var bottom = row + 1;
        var left = col - 1;
        var right = col + 1;

        swapped = false;

        if ( top  != -1 && cells[top][col].alt  == "hidden")
            swap (cells[row][col], cells[top][col]);
        else if (right != 4 && 
            cells [row][right].alt == "hidden")
            swap (cells[row][col], cells[row][right] );
        else if (bottom != 4 &&
            cells[bottom][col].alt == "hidden")
            swap(cells[row][col], cells[bottom][col]);
        else if (left != -1 &&
            cells[row][left].alt == "hidden")
            swap( cells[row][col], cells[row][left]);
        else    
            alert( "Illegal Move has been made" );

        checkWin();
    }

    function swap(firstCell, secondCell)
    {
        swapped = true;
        secondCell.src = firstCell.src;
        secondCell.alt = firstCell.alt;
        secondCell.style.display = "inline";
        firstCell.src = "9.gif";
        firstCell.alt = "hidden";
        firstCell.style.display = "none";
    }

    function checkWin()
    {
        var win = true;

        for(var i = 0; i<4; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j<4; j++)
                if (!(cells[i][j].src == i*4 + j + 1 + "9.gif"))
                    if (!(i == 3 && j == 3) ) 
                        win = false;

        if (win)
            if ( window.prompt( "Would you like to play again?", "yes") )
                placeNumbers();
    }
    //-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "setup()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(0,0)"
                id = "cell00" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(0,1)"
                id = "cell01" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(0,2)"
                id = "cell02" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(0,3)"
                id = "cell03" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(1,0)"
                id = "cell10" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(1,1)"
                id = "cell11" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(1,2)"
                id = "cell12" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(1,3)"
                id = "cell13" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(2,0)"
                id = "cell20" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(2,1)"
                id = "cell21" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(2,2)"
                id = "cell22" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(2,3)"
                id = "cell23" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(3,0)"
                id = "cell30" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(3,1)"
                id = "cell31" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(3,2)"
                id = "cell32" /></td>
            <td><img src = "9.gif" alt = "" onclick = "doClick(3,3)"
                id = "cell33" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean when you say that you cannot get it to work? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: no error code I should have just one sole image broken up into 15 pieces that i can move around in the grid.  Sort of like the puzzle with numbers.  Instead of just numbers it would have an image

Comment: Open up the error console in the browser, and you will see that you actually have an error message there. It would say `SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer` (or similar) and point you to the line where the error is.